# Capitalize the string but not first three lettres

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have strings based on airports codes, name and location.

i.e. :

```
var s = "BRU – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM";
```

The point here is to capitalize the string to get "Belgium" instead of "BELGIUM" but to keep the first tree letters upperCase.

How can I do this using jQuery or pure JavaScript ?

The output I need :

```
BRU - Brussels National, Brussels, Belgium
```

My try (the new string needs to populate a `<span>` content) :

```
$("#airport").html(s.toLowerCase()).css('text-transform', 'capitalize');
```

But the result when the `<span>` is rendered is :

```
Bru - Brussels National, Brussels, Belgium
```

How to keep the first three letters upperCase ?

Any tips are welcome and will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: split first the string from `-` then transform the second half then combine again

Comment: can you please share your HTML code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the first string always contains three letters, you could do something like this:

```js
var s = "BRU – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM";
$("#airport").html(s.slice(0, 3) + s.slice(3).toLowerCase()).css('text-transform', 'capitalize');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="airport"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace()` with `regex` for make this. Please try:

```js
var s = "BRU – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM";
result = s.split("–");
split = result[1].toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(result[0] + "-" + split)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first answer was on the right track but still made the "BRU" lowercase I've followed the same concept but hopefully got what you are looking for:

```
var str = "BRU – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM";
var newstr = str.replace(/[^–]*$/, function (letter) {
                        return letter.toLowerCase();
                    }).replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/g, function (letter) {
                        return letter.toUpperCase();
                    });
```

First, using regex

```
/[^–]*$/
```

I replace all the characters after the " - " with lowercase 
then also using regex

```
/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/g
```

I use a replace every first character with a uppercase

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In javascript,

```
    var s = "BRU – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM";
         var strToCap = s.split('-')[1];
        var result= '';
        strToCap = strToCap .split(' ');
        for (var chr = 0; chr < strToCap .length; chr++) {
          result+= strToCap [chr].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + strToCap [chr].substring(1, strToCap [chr].length).toLowerCase() + ' '
         }
        result = s.split('-')[0] + "-" + result ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by using below code:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="ContryCode">Bru – Brussels National, Brussels, BELGIUM</span>
<button id="btnConvert">
Convert To UperCase
</button>
<br/>
<span id="ConvertedCode"></span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
var code=$("#ContryCode").html();
var codeCapital = code.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
$("#ConvertedCode").html(codeCapital+""+code.slice(3))
});
```

It will convert to uppercase starting 3 letters of any string.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nk7kypyt/)

Hope it will helps you, thanks